# In Azure is there a way to tag a work item / user story with the repo and/or branch when creating / completing a pull request?

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, pull-request

We have a policy to always link a work item / user story to a PR. Is there a way to automatically tag the work item with the repo name / branch PR is merging into?

Currently doing this manually and trying to automate it (we use git with Azure Devops).

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below solution. How did it go?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I got put on an emergency project and haven't had the chance yet. It looks promising though and I'll make sure to mark the answer as soon as I try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to automatically tag the linked workitem when a PR is created. You can do this by adding a [build validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#build-validation) pipeline to the branch policy. And call the rest apis to tag the workitems in the build validation pipeline.  See below steps:

1, Create a build validation pipeline. Add a script task to call below rest apis.

> Call [Pull Request Work Items - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20work%20items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) api to get all the linked work item.

> Call [Work Items - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) api to add the tag to the work items

You can get the repo name by referring the predefined variable `$(Build.Repository.Name)` in the validation pipeline. See more [predefined variables here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). For below example scripts in powershell task.

```
#PR workitem list api
$url = "$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.Name)/pullRequests/$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)/workitems?api-version=6.1-preview.1"

$response= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"} -Method Get

#get all the related workitem ids
$ids = $response.value.id
#get the PR target branch name
$targetBranch = "$(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch)".split("/")[-1]
           
$newTag=  "$(Build.Repository.Name)/$($targetBranch)"

Foreach($id in $ids){

    $wurl = "$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/wit/workitems/$($id)?api-version=6.1-preview.3"

    # call get workitem api to get the existing tags
    $workitem = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $wurl -Headers @{authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"} -Method Get

    $tags = $workitem.fields.'System.Tags' + ";$($newTag)"

    $body =  @(
               @{
                op= "add";
                path= "/fields/System.Tags";
                value= "$($tags)"
              }
             )
    # add tags to work item.
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $wurl -Headers @{authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"} -Method patch -Body (ConvertTo-Json $body) -ContentType "application/json-patch+json"

}
```

In order to use the system token `$(System.AccessToken)` in above script. You need to check the option `Allow scripts to access the OAuth token` for your agent job. See below:

[image]

2, Configure the build validation for the branch policy of the target branch.

Go to the Branch policy page of the target branch. Add above pipeline as the build validation pipeline. See below:

[image]

After the build validation has been setup in the branch policy. When a PR is created. The validation pipeline will be triggered and add the tags to the workitems automatically.